# Converter Encoding de JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

Boa Tarde Galera,

Estou com uma dúvida, possuo um arquivo em JSON, que está com alguns caracteres não identificáveis, existe algum método para que eu possa setar o encoding dele em UFT-8? Pois preciso jogar esse JSON no mongo mas com os caracteres legíveis.

Comment: Poste o trecho do seu código, desta forma não é possível identificar qual é a linguagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça com o [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download)!

[image: Notepad++]

Normalmente vai identificar a codificação do seu arquivo. Se não, basta marcar a codificação atual e então clicar em *Converter para UTF-8*. Recomendo *sem BOM*.